# Set Cover Photo Facebook with JavaScript in a smarthphone

Tags: javascript, facebook, timeline, cover

Currently this works on desktop:

```
top.location.href = "https://www.facebook.com/me?preview_cover=" + e.id
```

However, in a smartphone this code does not work.

```
top.location.href ="https://www.m.facebook.com/me?preview_cover=" + e.id
```

How could this be done? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `https://www.m.facebook.com/` won’t work anywhere, because that domain does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, I added an extra dot. This should be the link: https://m.facebook.com/me?preview_cover=" + e.id